# How can I conjugate a past-potential verb?

Tags: verbs, potential-form

The conjugation rules for **present-potential** and **past** verb forms are well-documented online, but there doesn't seem to be as much information about **past-potential** conjugations.

If we can conjugate the present-potential form of a verb like this:

- **五段**

  - 飲**む** → 飲**める**
  - 飲**み**ます → 飲**め**ます
  - 飲**ま**ない → 飲**め**ない
  - 飲**み**ません → 飲**め**ません
- **一段**

  - 食べる → 食べ**られ**る
  - 食べます → 食べ**られ**ます
  - 食べない → 食べ**られ**ない
  - 食べません → 食べ**られ**ません
- **来る**

  - **く**る → **こられ**る
  - **き**ます → **こられ**ます
  - **こ**ない → **こられ**ない
  - **き**ません → **こられ**ません
- **する**

  - **す**る → **でき**る
  - **し**ます → **でき**ます
  - **し**ない → **でき**ない
  - **し**ません → **でき**ません

...then I'd imagine that the past-potential form could be conjugated as follows:

- **五段**

  - 飲ん**だ** → 飲ん**でる**
  - 飲**み**ました → 飲**め**ました
  - 飲**ま**なかった → 飲**め**なかった
  - 飲**み**ませんでした → 飲**め**ませんでした
- **一段**

  - 食べた → 食べ**られ**た
  - 食べました → 食べ**られ**ました
  - 食べなかった → 食べ**られ**なかった
  - 食べませんでした → 食べ**られ**ませんでした
- **来る**

  - **き**た → **こられ**た
  - **き**ました → **こられ**ました
  - **こ**なかった → **こられ**なかった
  - **き**ませんでした → **こられ**ませんでした
- **する**

  - **し**た → **でき**た
  - **し**ました → **でき**ました
  - **し**なかった → **でき**なかった
  - **し**ませんでした → **でき**ませんでした

I came across [this page](https://www.italki.com/question/401015) during my searches, and it seems to back up how I think that these conjugations should work (though it doesn't mention the rules for する or 来る).

Are the examples I've given above correct?

(Bonus question: Are past-potential conjugations uncommon/not actually used? I'm trying to understand why they don't seem to be mentioned as often as [the other variations](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1W%CD%E8%A4%EB_vk) are.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not conjugated like that, but it's an easy mistake to make :)

The mistake you made was trying to convert a past tense word into a past potential word, when you have to do the reverse to make it work.

That's to say, you need to convert a verb to its potential form and then turn that into its past.

食べる → 食べられる →  食べられた

飲む　→　飲める　→　飲めた